# Mapdist in R returning an error when passing a coordinates

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, ggmap

I am trying to use the mapdist function in ggmap package in R but I am getting the error Warning: Reverse geocoding failed with error: This API project is not authorized to use this API. below is my code

```
> p1
[1] -77.1365  38.8190
> p2
[1] -77.0625  38.8049
> mapdist(p1, p2, mode = "walking")
Warning: Reverse geocoding failed with error:
This API project is not authorized to use this API.

Warning: Reverse geocoding failed with error:
This API project is not authorized to use this API.

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  from  to    mode   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 NA    NA    walking
```

I have tested the codes below to test if I have correctly enabled all APIs in google console and it works

```
> (wh <- as.numeric(geocode("the white house, dc")))
Source : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=the+white+house,+dc&key=xxx
[1] -77.03653  38.89768
> (lm <- as.numeric(geocode("lincoln memorial washington dc")))
Source : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=lincoln+memorial+washington+dc&key=xxx
[1] -77.05018  38.88927
> mapdist(wh, lm, mode = "walking")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for being too lazy to look up all the necessary data, but what makes you think that `mapdist` and `geocode` use the same API?

Comment: i followed this https://rdrr.io/github/dkahle/ggmap/man/mapdist.html